# How to force load tiles for lower resolution

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-3

How to load tiles from higher zoom level (lower resolution) on lower zoom when lower zoom level tiles are not available at all ? Is this possible ? For example: I have tiles for zoom 8 and higher and need that map on zoom 6,7 load tiles from zoom 8 and scale it in browser.

```
    var countedResoultions = [650251.6299617786, 325125.8149808893, 162562.90749044466, 81281.45374522233, 40640.726872611165, 20320.363436305583, 10160.181718152791, 5080.090859076396, 2540.045429538198, 1270.022714769099, 635.0113573845495, 317.5056786922747];

    var customExtent = [-491187.1897463986, -53831.96192823257, 890456.9786693857, 877455.310353267];

    var layers = [new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.XYZ({
            projection: 'EPSG:2180',
            tileGrid: new ol.tilegrid.TileGrid({
                origin: [101235.72703025967, 781405.7611248483],
                extent: customExtent,
                resolutions: countedResolutions, 
            }),
            tileUrlFunction: function(coord){
                console.log('gridZoom' coord[0]);
                // not standard OSM url
                // ...
            }
        })
    })];


    var map = new ol.Map({
        layers: layers,
        target: 'map',
        view: new ol.View({         
            center: ol.proj.transform([20.92,52.23], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
            zoom: 6,
            maxZoom: 14
        })
    });
```

What is strange for me, that zoom on `ol.View` (i've registered listener on change) is not the same that zoom value (`coord[0]`) in `tileUrlFunction`. For viewZoom=6 -> gridZoom=9, viewZoom=7 -> gridZoom=10, viewZoom=8 -> gridZoom=11.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is possible. All you need to do is to find out the resolutions you need to use.
So lets say you want to display OSM tiles in all available resolutions and you want to add a few more zoom levels so user can zoom in more.

here is the default resolutions for OSM:

`var osmRes = [156543.0339, 78271.51695, 39135.758475, 19567.8792375, 9783.93961875, 4891.969809375, 2445.9849046875, 1222.99245234375, 611.496226171875, 305.7481130859375, 152.87405654296876, 76.43702827148438, 38.21851413574219, 19.109257067871095, 9.554628533935547, 4.777314266967774, 2.388657133483887, 1.1943285667419434, 0.5971642833709717];`

And here is the same resolutions + a few more:

`var customRes = [156543.0339, 78271.51695, 39135.758475, 19567.8792375, 9783.93961875, 4891.969809375, 2445.9849046875, 1222.99245234375, 611.496226171875, 305.7481130859375, 152.87405654296876, 76.43702827148438, 38.21851413574219, 19.109257067871095, 9.554628533935547, 4.777314266967774, 2.388657133483887, 1.1943285667419434, 0.5971642833709717,0.41999977320012255, 0.2799998488000817,0.13999992440004086, 0.08399995464002451, 0.05599996976001634, 0.02799998488000817]`

Now all you need to do is to pass the desired resolutions to the view of your map, like so:

```
var raster = new ol.layer.Tile({
  source: new ol.source.OSM()
});

var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [raster],
  target: 'map',
  view: new ol.View({
    resolutions : customRes,
    center: [-11000000, 4600000],
    resolution    : 156543.0339
  })
});
```

here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p_tsagkis/vqsn1bpL/) to see it in action.

If you are not sure about the resoloution but you know the scales you want to use, the following functions may help you.

```
/**
 * get the resolution out of scale
 * @param {number} scale as declared in the config eg 50000
 * @returns {window.webGisApp.main.resolutions}
 */
function getResolutionFromScale(scale){
var dpi = 25.4 / 0.28;  
var mpu = ol.proj.METERS_PER_UNIT['m'];
var res = scale / (mpu * 39.37 * dpi); 
return res;
}
/**
 * get the resolution out of scale
 * @param {number} res the resolution
 * @returns {webGisApp.main.resolutions}
 */
function getScaleFromResolution(res){
var dpi = 25.4 / 0.28;  
var mpu = ol.proj.METERS_PER_UNIT['m'];
var scale = res * mpu * 39.37 * dpi; 
return scale;
}
```

Comment: I have more complicated situation, because i have custom `ol.source.XYZ` source with counted `resolutions` in `ol.tilegrid.TileGrid` option. It works ok, but when zoom is below some value, there is no tiles to get and need that map use scaled tiles from higher zoom (get more tiles and scale it down).

Comment: You should configure your map view with the extra resolutions and keep those you have in your tilegrid. Ol3 should do the client zoom of tiles. I have done the same in the past and it works fine. If you provide your code I may help you

Comment: You probably missing the matrixids. Check this fiddle --> http://jsfiddle.net/p_tsagkis/5sd4a4dw/

Comment: I've swapped `ol.tilegrid.TileGrid` to `ol.tilegrid.WMTS` and set option `matrixIds`, but nothing change.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can not test your code as your tile url is missing. But the example I provide uses a non-standard tile service, so it should work as on my fiddle. What is the `maxZoom: 14` within your map view, maybe this is causing your malfunction.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `preload` option of Layer

https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/preload.html
https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.layer.Tile.html